Clip polygon with vector points freehand
I am trying to crop/clip a polygon with overlapping vector data points in QGIS, so that I can extract all points from a certain area. However, I want to clip not based on the polygon but on a freehand shape. I can't figure out how to do this.
Here is the map:

I am trying to extract all point info from general areas, like such:


Hand draw a new layer and proceed as before

You can also select feature by polygon, right-click the layer and export selected features

I second the 'select feature by polygon' approach. Select the portions of the layer you need portion of the map (i.e., N, S, E, W), and export them to new layers one at a time.

You can use the "polygons to lines" tool ,
then paste in the created output shapefile your boundaries which from what I understand are lines ,
then trim them in the boundary of the polygon perimeter ,
and then use the "polygonize" tool to create your sub-area polygons in your boundary lines.
Finally, give an ID to those sub-area polygons and run "join attributes by location" or the "intersection" tool.
